# Python - discord.py, How to fix "Event loop is closed"

Tags: python, discord.py

im a beginner in programming, im trying to start my first discord bot, code below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents = discord.Intents.all())
@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print("BOT connected")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello. hey ")
     
TOKEN = "my token"
client.run(TOKEN)
```

and after many tries of running i have a huge scary error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\2\server\dsmachines.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.run("ODg2MjEyNTk5MjE2MjM0NTE2.YTyTzA.020rByPUfY8rDsw9iKDCi2jUZuM")
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run   
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000002203C0C0E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000002203C0C0E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
PS C:\Users\ыв> & C:/Users/ыв/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe b:/2/server/dsmachines.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\2\server\dsmachines.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intenPS C:\Users\ыв> & C:/Users/ыв/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe b:/2/server/dsmachines.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\2\server\dsmachines.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000267B2E00E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
PS C:\Users\ыв> & C:/Users/ыв/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe b:/2/server/dsmachines.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\2\server\dsmachines.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https:ts instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000026F065D0E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
PS C:\Users\ыв> & C:/Users/ыв/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe b:/2/server/dsmachines.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\2\server\dsmachines.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001A85999FE50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
PS C:\Users\ыв> & C:/Users/ыв/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe b:/2/server/dsmachines.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\2\server\dsmachines.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001E2C8C4FE50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed"
```

idk what i need to do, i checked a lot of forums with a similar problems
but they all had a mistake, like they entered a small b in `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents = discord.Intents.all())`  instead of a capital one or something like that,
sorry guys if i look stupid in your eyes, but i just cant find a way to fix this
thx in advance everyone

Answer (score 0):

From the error message:

> discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting
> privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the
> developer portal. It is recommended to go to
> https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the
> privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not
> possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.

What this mean is you are requesting intents that you have not enabled from developer page. You are requesting intents using:
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents = discord.Intents.all())`.
You can enable them from bot tab of discord developer portal(below bot's token code). For `discord.Intents.all()` enable both privileged gateway intents.